# Stop External users with 'contribute' permission mass mailing everyone in AD (hide all users in AD from external users)

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, external-sharing

Our clients each have their own site on our tenant.  They have contribute permission level (within their own site) to allow them to upload documents for us to process. With 'contribute' they also get the button to "SHARE".  When this is selected they can start to type letters in the selection box and can start to populate the box.  They cannot press send, but but this point they could copy and past into an email and bulk email!  How do I stop them seeing ALL USERS in the AD.  Even users that are not in their site!

Thanks